# Permutations of a list of objects without reverse duplicates in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

How can i generate unique permutations such that if any two permutations are reverse of each other (i.e. [1,2,3,4] and [4,3,2,1]), they are considered equal and only one of them should be contained in the final result.

```
For Example:
Carrying out permutation on [1,2,3] should give the following result:
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
```

This is code used but this generates all permutations including the reverse duplicates

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
        {
            if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });

            return GetPermutations(list, length - 1)
                .SelectMany((t) => list.Where(e => !t.Contains(e)),
                    (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
        }
```

Comment: Can you generate all permutations?

Comment: yes. I have updated my question with my code

Comment: Simply compare the first and the last element and only include the permutations where the first element is smaller.

Comment: IMO -4 is a bit harsh for a first question, without one comment explaining what's wrong or what can be done to improve the post?

Comment: @Dennis_E, can you please help with a sample code. Please do note that the permutation involves a list of objects and not integers

Answer (score 1):

Select only the permutations where the first element is smaller than the last.
Example:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
foreach (var permutation in GetPermutations(list, 3))
{
    int[] array = permutation.ToArray();
    if (array.First() < array.Last())
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));
}
```

You need some way of comparing the first and last object. You can also replace

```
if (array.First() < array.Last())
```

with

```
if (list.IndexOf(array.First()) < list.IndexOf(array.Last()))
```

or whatever works to distinguish 2 items.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I will try this out. Sorry for my late response